# Missing data in MLR RStudio

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm **really** new to coding and to R so struggling to find an answer I can understand, or recognise if it is an answer. I'm hoping someone(s) can help.

I'm trying to conduct a multiple linear regression in R.

The data is from a survey of 561 people. Here's a sample of the first 12 lines of data.

[image]

I want to look for the significanc between a positive attitude, which is a mean of 4 Likert-scale questions (dependent variable), and the explanatory variable of age, gender, user and format.

I carried out the code all in one:

```
mlrpositive.lm <- lm(mean_pos ~ age + gender + format + user, data = mlr.data)
```

I noticed it was missing explanatory variables, for example in age it was missing '18-24', gender was missing 'female', user was missing 'no', and format missing 'Audio'.

I carried out each one individually and got the same result.

```
positive.gender.lm <- lm(mean_pos ~ gender, data = mlr.data)
```

[image]

I don't know how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. When you run a regression on factors, the first factor is captured by the intercept. It's not possible to show as many separate factors as you have categories, because the regression would become undefined and would fail to run.

This is analogous to the problem in algebra if you see `5 = x + y`; there isn't enough information for a numeric answer, so we could justify any value for x (and come up with a fitting y counterpart).

Similarly, we could justify an infinite range of values for the first factor, provided we adjusted the other coefficients to accommodate. Instead, we treat the variable value that is not referenced explicitly as the "reference" group, against which the others are compared.

https://stattrek.com/multiple-regression/dummy-variables.aspx

> When defining dummy variables, a common mistake is to define too many
> variables. If a categorical variable can take on k values, it is
> tempting to define k dummy variables. Resist this urge. Remember, you
> only need k - 1 dummy variables.
>
> A kth dummy variable is redundant; it carries no new information. And
> it creates a severe multicollinearity problem for the analysis. Using
> k dummy variables when only k - 1 dummy variables are required is
> known as the dummy variable trap. Avoid this trap!

https://otexts.com/fpp2/useful-predictors.html#seasonal-dummy-variables

> Many beginners will try to add a seventh dummy variable for the
> seventh category. This is known as the “dummy variable trap”, because
> it will cause the regression to fail. There will be one too many
> parameters to estimate when an intercept is also included. The general
> rule is to use one fewer dummy variables than categories. So for
> quarterly data, use three dummy variables; for monthly data, use 11
> dummy variables; and for daily data, use six dummy variables, and so
> on.
>
> The interpretation of each of the coefficients associated with the
> dummy variables is that it is *a measure of the effect of that category
> relative to the omitted category.*

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering if you knew if there was a way of getting that data from the Intercept line as it is important for the significance analysis. Using the equation, AGE 18-24 = 3.39 + (-0.05) + (-0.12) + (0.11) + (-0.16) + (0.11) would this give me the estimate for 18-24 but how do i get the PR(>|t|) number. I apologise if this is basic stuff, but my time using code and R can be measured in days and I do not have a statistics or mathmatical background.